# How to populate inlineformsets in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I have an `inlineformset_factory`,

```
CoinInfoFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(Portfolio,CoinInfo
              ,form = CoinForm,can_delete=False,extra=1)
```

That produces my `inlineformset`. But when I try to populate it in my updateview, the data is unbound, and produces the error:" (Hidden field portfolio) The inline foreign key did not match the parent instance primary key."

```
class UpdatePortFolio(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Portfolio
    fields = ('title','is_public')
    template_name = 'hello/edit_create_portfolio.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        portfolioForm = PortfolioForm(data=request.POST)
        self.object = portfolioForm.save(commit=False)
        data = self.get_context_data()
        if 'add_coin' in request.POST:
            cp = request.POST.copy()
            cp['coininfo_set-TOTAL_FORMS'] = int(cp.get('coininfo_set-TOTAL_FORMS')) + 1
            data['CoinInfoFormSet'] = CoinInfoFormSet(cp, prefix='coininfo_set')
        for form in data['CoinInfoFormSet']:
            print(form,'\n\n')
        return render(request, 'hello/edit_create_portfolio.html', data)


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(UpdatePortFolio, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print(self.get_object())
        portfolio = self.get_object()

        if self.request.POST:
            data['CoinInfoFormSet'] = CoinInfoFormSet(instance=portfolio, prefix='coininfo_set')
        else:
            data['CoinInfoFormSet'] = CoinInfoFormSet(instance=portfolio, prefix='coininfo_set')
        return data
```

How should I populate my inlineformset?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you do not specify the instance for CoinInfoFormSet(). You need to link the CoinInfoFormSet object with the form. I.e. get the id of the Portfolio or Coin you're trying to update and assigned it as the instance of CoinInfoFormSet.

Comment: The instance is not the problem, since self.get_object() is an instance of Portfolio. Also when I render the inline forms they work. However i cannot post them since they are not bound.